# Transform an azimuth measured in a given projection system to its value in a separate projection system

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, pyqgis, reprojection-mathematics

I have a set of polygons in which one of the attributes is azimuth. This azimuth was measured in ESPG:3310 (California Albers). I want to transform this measure to ESPG:4326 (WGS 84). I know the values are different as when measuring the azimuth of a line in the two projections, I get a different value.

E.G. if I draw a line in QGIS and measure the azimuth between the first and last points using this code:

```
degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry)))
```

I get a value of 179.721 when my layer is projected in ESPG:4326 and a value of 180.08 when projected in ESPG:3310.

I want to convert the value without the actual line being available to me. So I can't simply reproject the layer, but have to reproject the value.
Unsure if that would be necessary to have the location of the measured line, but if it is, we could use the centroid of the polygon.

Comment: Maybe you should use reverse engineering approach... use stored azimuth value to construct the desired geometry, then reproject it and then measure azimuth in desired projection...

Comment: yeah, I thought that might be the longer way around. So create a line of given azimuth from centroid of the polygon, than transform the line to the different coordinate system and store the value of this new line in the polygon's attribute table. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: It is necessary to know the location of the measuring point of the azimuth because it's affected by the grid convergence of the projection. The azimuth of the line in 4326 doesn't make much sense. Are you calculating the geodetic azimuth or the "Cartesian" azimuth because the lat-lon coordinates are being treated as if they're 2D?